# bindService 'is undefined' when changing from Activity to Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I want to change my from extend Activity to extend Fragment, but among the errors seen are:

bindService -> The method bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int) is undefined for the filename, where my filename is changed from extending Activity to Fragment?

Anyone faced the same problem? I am developing with the v4.support library

Comment: Nikita's solution works :)  You should accept the answer sebastian

Answer (score 5):

Try `getActivity().bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int)`

There is no `bindService` method in fragmet. But every fragment placed inside some activity you can use it to bind service.